# Effect of spectral shift on the eigenvalues of a real symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose a matrix A(real symmetric) is changed to A − σ I, where σ is any scalar quantity and I is the
identity matrix. Explain what happens to the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of A?

I am unable to figure it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $v_k$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_k$ so that $Av_k=\lambda_kv_k$ then we have
$$(A-\sigma I)v_k=\lambda_kv_k-\sigma v_k=(\lambda_k-\sigma)v_k$$
Can you work out what the corresponding eigenvalue and eigenvector of $A+\sigma I$ is?